# If I ship a DLL that use IPP library, should I also ship IPP DLLs?

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, lib, intel-ipp

I was reading this interessant [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/understanding-cpu-optimized-code-used-in-intel-ipp) about IPP Dispatcher. At some points its written: *Dispatching refers to the process of detecting CPU features at run-time and then selecting the Intel IPP optimized library set that corresponds to your CPU. For example, in the \ia32\ipp directory, the ippip8.dll library file contains the 32-bit optimized image processing libraries for processors with Intel® SSE4.2; ‘ippi’ refers to the image processing library, ‘p8’ refers to 32-bit SSE4.2 architecture.*

Does it mean that if I release a DLL using `ipp.h`, when I ship to customers, they also need the DLLs version of the `IPP` Library? Or are they automatically compiled and linked with the `.lib`s in the final build?

I don't get that `DLL example` on the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to ship all of them, there is an automatic dispatch that is done at runtime. If a library is "missing", then the runtime will choose the lower compatible runtime (so you should at least have the SSE2 runtime).

Comment: Uhm, its not clear at all the process. This is what I think to have understand: let say I build `MyPlug.dll`, which use `ippsExp_64f`. When I run it on different machines/cpu, by default `ippInit` will automatically catch which CPU is running, and will dispatch to the optimized (overloaded) `ippsExp_64f` function. But all of these overloads are within the program itself or dispatcher will call IPP DLL? (so the user also need them alongside my program)?

Comment: In the libraries.

Comment: What do you mean "In the libraries"? Both .lib and .dll are libraries. But the ones will be included in a final (unique) dll (.lib), while the others need to be sent separately.

Comment: The .lib are the definitions for the .dll (if you go for linking against the dll). They don't contain code.

Comment: Aren't .lib collections of already-compiled object files which will be linked?

Comment: Not always, it's the same extension for the definition file for dll that you have to use. If you link against such a .lib, then you get a runtime link against the dll. For pure static libraries, you don't have the additional dll dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184129/discussion-between-markzzz-and-matthieu-brucher).